# Creating a safe environment on (backup) server

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync

I want to use my server as backup server and let other users let their data backup to it aswell. I was thinking of using rsync instead of FTP (due to the obvious reasons), however how would I prevent user A to be browsing user B's files? If using rsync over SSH (preferable method due to encryption) then the user has to be CHrooted probably.

So, how can I set up a safe environment so users cannot browse eachother's files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even without chroot there's this little thing called file permissions.

Just make sure user home directories (`/home/user` or wherever they are located) have `0700`, or `u+rwx,go-rwx` permissions, so they can't enter each other's directories at all.